# Parsing XML file, one tag is skipped

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to load an xml file and parse it. I have an config file where I defined array with names that I am interested in, so after loading the file I compare the tags with my predefined array and if the value matches then use the tag(name) as index into array and save its value. Problem is that it is always skipping the tag with name that is first in config array. Also, `LoadCsvReport` should work, except few error checking is it good code ? I am learning OOP, but i think i don't use any of it.

```
class LoadAdReport extends CI_Controller

{

/*
 * @return array[][]
 * */
public function LoadCsvReport()
{
    require "config.php";
    $key = array();
    $values = array();
    $flag = false;


    $csvfile = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/result.csv", "r");

    while ($file = fgetcsv($csvfile)) {
        if (!$flag) {
            /*Loop through config array which contains names of columns of our interest
              If row from file contains name from config, then that name will have assigned
              index of that column
            */
            foreach ($bing as $name)
                if ($value = array_search($name, $file)) {
                    $key[$name] = $value;
                    $flag = true;
                }
            //After column indexes are assigned to names skip current row
            if ($flag)
                continue;
        }


        if ($flag) {

            foreach ($key as $columnName => $index) {
                /*Get columnname and index, items from $file[$index] are assign to array
                  corresponding array with columnName as index
                */
                if ($file[$index] === "-")
                    break;
                $values[$columnName][] = $file[$index];
                //$key[$index] = array($item => $file[$item]);

            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($values as $key => $val)
        foreach ($val as $lol => $item)
            echo $key . "=>" . $item . "<br/>";

    fclose($csvfile);
}

public function LoadXmlReport()
{
    require "config.php";


    $items = array();
    $xmlfile = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__) . "/xmlfile.xml");
    foreach ($xmlfile as $key => $value)
        foreach ($value as $key => $item) {
            if ($item == "-") {
                break;
            } elseif (array_search($key, $bing))
                $items[$key][] = $item;
        }


    foreach ($items as $key => $val)
        foreach ($val as $lol => $item)
            echo $key . "=>" . $item . "<br/>";


}
}
```

This is my XML file

```
<root>
<row>
    <Status>Enabled</Status>
    <Keyword>Toaletna voda</Keyword>
    <Campaign>Lešenari</Campaign>
    <Adgroup>Lešenaris</Adgroup>
    <BidStrategyType>InheritFromParent</BidStrategyType>
    <Bid>0.05</Bid>
    <Matchtype>Broad</Matchtype>
    <Clicks>0</Clicks>
    <Impr.>0</Impr.>
    <Conv.>0</Conv.>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Status>Enabled</Status>
    <Keyword>lyžička</Keyword>
    <Campaign>Lešenari</Campaign>
    <Adgroup>Lešenaris</Adgroup>
    <BidStrategyType>InheritFromParent</BidStrategyType>
    <Bid>0.05</Bid>
    <Matchtype>Broad</Matchtype>
    <Clicks>0</Clicks>
    <Impr.>0</Impr.>
    <Conv.>0</Conv.>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Status>Search total</Status>
    <Keyword>-</Keyword>
    <Campaign>-</Campaign>
    <Adgroup>-</Adgroup>
    <BidStrategyType>-</BidStrategyType>
    <Bid>-</Bid>
    <Matchtype>-</Matchtype>
    <Clicks>0</Clicks>
    <Impr.>0</Impr.>
    <Conv.>0</Conv.>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Status>Content total</Status>
    <Keyword>-</Keyword>
    <Campaign>-</Campaign>
    <Adgroup>-</Adgroup>
    <BidStrategyType>-</BidStrategyType>
    <Bid>-</Bid>
    <Matchtype>-</Matchtype>
    <Clicks>0</Clicks>
    <Impr.>0</Impr.>
    <Conv.>0</Conv.>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Status>Deleted items total</Status>
    <Keyword>-</Keyword>
    <Campaign>-</Campaign>
    <Adgroup>-</Adgroup>
    <BidStrategyType>-</BidStrategyType>
    <Bid>-</Bid>
    <Matchtype>-</Matchtype>
    <Clicks>0</Clicks>
    <Impr.>0</Impr.>
    <Conv.>0</Conv.>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Status>Overall total</Status>
    <Keyword>-</Keyword>
    <Campaign>-</Campaign>
    <Adgroup>-</Adgroup>
    <BidStrategyType>-</BidStrategyType>
    <Bid>-</Bid>
    <Matchtype>-</Matchtype>
    <Clicks>0</Clicks>
    <Impr.>0</Impr.>
    <Conv.>0</Conv.>
  </row>
</root>
```

and this is my config file

```
$bing = array(
"Adgroup",
"Campaign",
"Keyword",
"Clicks",
"Impr.",
"Conv.",
"Bid",
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
elseif (array_search($key, $bing))
```

The function `arrach_search` returns the array index where the passed value was found. For the first item in the array, that is `0`. But `if(0)` equals to `if(false)`.

You need to differentiate between the return value `0` for "I 've found the item at the 0th position in the array" and the return value `false` for "I haven't found the item in the array at all":

Correct:

```
elseif  (array_search($key, $bing) !== FALSE)
```